# Can Thunderbird handle all existing folders on hotmail account?

Tags: thunderbird

I was wondering: is it true that Thunderbird cannot show folders on hotmail account that were created using your internet browser?

Comment: Off-topic question. This is not a place for subjective or opinionated discussions.

Comment: @Elysium consider rephrasing the question. In its current form, it is certainly off-topic and would be voted for closure.

Comment: @Mahesh Close it please if you want to. I am not using Thunderbird anymore. Thanks.

Comment: @Elysium In that case, deleting it yourself would save trouble for our mods. and btw I dont have any close votes yet.. and ya, sorry to see u leave thunderbird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell it can't.
Hotmail doesn't do imap. Thunderbird can only get mail from hotmail via the pop3 protocol which doesn't have any folder support.
iPhones & iPads seem to be able to use some Exchange protocol - thunderbird and apple mail can't.
Protocol wars are painful.